# Alerting Order of Dropped Elements WITHOUT using jQuery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

https://jsfiddle.net/ianderso222/y9ynouxs/36/

I hope this makes sense, If I need to elaborate I will do so.

Right now the code is working pretty well, doing everything I need it to except this one issue. I just need to alert the order that the squares have been dropped in, after all 4 have been placed.

So, if square4 is placed in the large container, that would show up first in the alert. If square2 is in the last, smallest box it would be last in the list, and so on.

I would use sortable but I am afraid it would not work with the current setup. The resizing to different sized containers would not work, or at least I was not able to get it to work. If there is a way to keep the current structure of resizing to fill container and sliding into place I would say do that, but from everything I have seen I feel I would have to essentially start from scratch.

Here is the JavaScript, pardon the messy code:

```
$('.holderList li').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {

    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;

    console.log(draggable.attr('id') + ' is ' + droppable.attr('id'));

    var $this = $(this);
    ui.draggable.position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: $this,
      using: function(pos) {
        $(this).animate(pos, 200, "linear");
      }
    });

    ui.draggable.addClass('dropped');
    ui.draggable.data('droppedin', $(this));
    $(this).droppable('disable');

    setTimeout(function() {
      var dragID = ui.draggable;

      if (!$(".ui-droppable").not(".ui-droppable-disabled").length) {
        alert(draggable.attr('id'));
      }
    }, 400);
  },
});

$(".square").draggable({
  stack: ".square",
  revert: function(event, ui) {
    //overwrite original position
    $(this).data("ui-draggable").originalPosition = {
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }
      //return boolean
    return !event;
  },
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var draggable = $(this).data("ui-draggable");

    $.each(draggable.snapElements, function(index, element) {
      ui = $.extend({}, ui, {
        snapElement: $(element.item),
        snapping: element.snapping
      });
      if (element.snapping) {
        if (!element.snappingKnown) {
          element.snappingKnown = true;
          draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
        }
      } else if (element.snappingKnown) {
        element.snappingKnown = false;
        draggable._trigger("snapped", event, ui);
      }
    });
    if ($(this).data('droppedin')) {
      $(this).data('droppedin').droppable('enable');
      $(this).data('droppedin', null)
      $(this).removeClass('dropped')
    }
  },
  snap: ".holder",
  snapMode: "inner",
  snapTolerance: 8,
  snapped: function(event, ui) {
    var squareWidth = ui.snapElement.width();
    var squareHeight = ui.snapElement.height();



    ui.helper.css({
      width: squareWidth,
      height: squareHeight
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my solution:

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y9ynouxs/55/)

First it assigns a `data-current` attribute to the `droppable` holder on every drop and sets it to the id of the `draggable`.

Then it itterates trough all the `.holder` elements and prints their `data-current`

Simple but works.

```
 // On single drop
 drop: function(event,ui){
 ...
   droppable.attr('data-current', draggable.attr('id') );
 }

 //On all dropped
 $('.holder').each(function(el){
   console.log($(this).attr('data-current'));
 });
```